# Как изменить права на вложенные директории без цикла

Tags: php

Команда

```
chmod("/home/www/tools/", 0777);
```

меняет права только на папку tools, на вложенные не меняет.

Если через консоль, то командой

```
chmod -R 777 tools
```

можно поменять права рекурсивно.

А как это сделать через PHP-функцию chmod, не перебирая циклом все вложенные папки и файлы?

Comment: Разве что только через exec

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> А как это сделать через PHP-функцию chmod, не перебирая циклом

Никак.

Comment: Дополню для понимания. `chmod` - как утилита вызывает `chmod()` - библиотечную функцию. Для удобства пользователя утилита выполняет некоторые дополнительные операции. В частности рекурсивно перебирает файлы и директории и для каждого вызывает `chmod()`. PHP-функция - по сути - обертка над библиотечной C-функцией у которой функционал минимален